# How to use PGP to encrypt all your mails (even received)?

Tags: email, gmail, osx-mountain-lion, gnupg

I would like to know if it is possible to encrypt all my mail with my one public key so the mail provider (gmail) cannot read its contents?

I am using OSX Mountain Lion

Answer (score 1):

You can not control how other people send their mail, so you can not protect all **received** email before you get it. (And if you are worried about your provider, by then they already had a chance to read it).

As for sending: If you control your own computer then you can encrypt whatever you store on it. Both for mail (and other files) which you want to keep as well as mail you are about to send.

If you do not use your own computer but the gmail web interface then you are back at their mercy.

Comment: I understand the mail provider goal can't be met. However I don't expect all senders to send encrypted mails. I want to encrypt the mail after receiving. This helps in the scenario if the A/C was hacked all the contents would be encrypted. I can only decrypt them on my local client.

Comment: You can either download (and wipe) all mail to a place you full control. (E.g. your own computer running the right mail software and using full disk encryption), or download all mail to your client, encrypt them and try to store them back at google. I am not sure how you would do the last while retaining all the received from, reply to etc etc information.